# Mock out database layer in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I am working on writing some unit tests around an application which uses SQLAlchemy. I would like to abstract/mock away the database layer and just test the object.

For example classes:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", backref=backref('children', order_by=id))
```

What I would like to achieve while unit testing is something like follows:

```
parent = Mock()
child = Child(parent)
assertTrue(someMethod(child))
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish something along those lines?

Comment: Can't speak to sqlalchemy but I usually find that I end up creating a repository layer to encapsulate data access and then create a mock that just stores objects in lists.

Comment: A bit late: You can use https://github.com/miki725/alchemy-mock `AlchemyMagicMock` or `UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock` to mock out SQLAlchemy sessions which should enable you to test returns of data layer.